# Apply a product discount if orders are picked up

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a Drupal Commerce site where customers get to choose whether to ship the order, or if they want to come and pick it up. Picking up is free, obviously.
This part works already, and I don't need help with.

There is an additional discount that should apply to one specific product only when the customer comes to pick up his order. There could be other products in the order besides the one specific product, and those products would not be discounted. This discount would be applied if "picking up" is specified during the check out process.
I'm having a bit of trouble getting the event/conditions right: it seems to me that no shipping method has been picked when the sell price is calculated.

Menno

Comment: Will you provide some option like dropdown to let user select how he/she want to get delivered ?

Comment: Have you tried the [Commerce Pickup](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_pickup) module?

Comment: The free versus pickup part already works; I need to figure out how to apply the additional discount for pickup.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the shipping methods themselves using rules? I would try to edit the rule for the Pickup shipping method and see if I could add the discount from the Actions of that Rule.

If you know how to use Rules Components, you could further encapsulate this so all the discount-related stuff was in a separate Rule Component.